# Resize resolution of monitor with windows forms c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio, resolution

I need to create a toolbar in Windows Form. I want that this toolbar stays on top and don't disturb the normal operation with the pc...so the property TopMost or similar is not useful for me, because some objects of the pc goes on back. I want that, when I open this form, the resolution of desktop "resize" to make space for toolbar.

I hope that i'm cleared to explain my problem...Many thanks

EDIT 1:
I want this specific effect! min 2.15: youtube.com/watch?v=VDK6Zrbo0EY

Comment: Are you after something that just auto-hides or something that resizes the other windows and then restores them when you hide it?

Comment: I prefer the second answer... I saw this effect in a program called "Eviacam"...when you open this program, the toolbar on top resize the entire desktop... you can see the effect that i want in this video (min 2.15): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDK6Zrbo0EY

Comment: These are called *AppBars* and are created via the `SHAppBarMessage` API, many examples of this in C# E.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C - Note this is nothing to do with *resolution*, it simply changes the available client area of the desktop.